# Hosting WCF REST Service as a child application in IIS

Tags: rest, wcf, iis

I am trying to host a WCF RESTful service in IIS as a child application under and existing Site but it will not work. It works fine when I host it as a Site by itself, but the problem is that both Sites share the same port numbers, port 80 (http) and port 443(https). Can anything help with how to get around this?

Comment: any error return?

Comment: Coz i have the same stucture but fortunately all are working.. All Sites are child with WCF service. With all same port number.

Answer (score 0):

You must select the default site, do right click and **add application** or **create a virtual folder** to point to default folder where your service is in dev...

[image: Add application or create virtual directory in IIS]

If you choose the first you need to create a file system of the service, with publish in Visual Studio.

[image: Create a file system 1]

and

[image: Create a file system 2].

So with this approach you can use the same port with different route.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for for taking your time to answer the question. I was able to get the solution myself. It was because I did not configure HTTPS when I hosted the service in IIS. After I configured the HTTPS, everything works great.